# Update text file on button click

Tags: php, jquery, text-files, overwrite

I want to make a website where there is a button, and when you click it make it change some text (saying either true/false). The text must change when the user clicks the button, but not just for the one user, for every user that's on the site.

The way I'm trying to do it is I have a text file, and so far all I've got is some text on the page that every 500 milliseconds is refreshing to display whatever is in the text file.

So now all I need to do is update the text file when the button is clicked. What's the best way I could do this? (I want to be able to press the button on the computer hosting the site OR another computer accessing the site.)

Thanks,
Fjpackard.

---

*Update*

index.php:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div id="theDiv"></div>

</body>

<script>

$("document").ready(function(){
    $("button").remove();
    setInterval(function(){
         $("#theDiv").load("file.txt");
    },500);
    var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);
    if (agentID) {

        // mobile code here

    }
    else {
        $("body").prepend("<button>Toggle</button>");
        $("#theDiv").css("visibility","none");

        $("button").click(function(){
            myClick();
        });
    }
});

function myClick() {
                var url = ''; //put the url for the php
                value = $.post("", {}).done(
                    function(data) {
                        $('#theDiv').html(data);
                    }
                );
            }

</script>
```

script.php:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
    {
        $file = 'file.txt';

        $previous = file_get_contents($file);
        if ($previous === 'true')
        {
            file_put_contents($file, 'false');
            echo 'false'; //this is what we return to the client
        }
        else
        {
            file_put_contents($file, 'true');
            echo 'true'; //this is what we return to the client
        }
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: did you try anything? any code sample?

Comment: I tried:
        $fp = fopen('file.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, 'false');
        fclose($fp);

And:
        file_put_contents('file.txt','test');

No luck yet :(

Comment: I have seen a similar construct at [Use buttons to post to a php script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20295500/402022). I'll try to adapt it for your case.

Comment: Thanks! How's it going...? :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110399/how-to-edit-the-contents-of-a-file-on-button-click-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be reading a file on the server with the name "file.txt".

Let's say you have this code to refresh the page each 500 milliseconds:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    function myClick()
    {
        //somehow get and change the value
        /*var value = ???*/
        $('#theDiv').html(value ? 'true' : 'false');
    }

    $("document").ready(
        function()
        {
            setInterval(
                function()
                {
                    $("#theDiv").load("file.txt");
                },
                500
            );
        }
    );
</script>
<div id="theDiv"></div>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="myClick()">
```

> So now all I need to do is update the text file when the button is clicked. What's the best way I could do this? (I want to be able to press the button on the computer hosting the site OR another computer accessing the site.)

script.php:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
    {
        $file = 'file.txt';

        $previous = file_get_contents($file);
        if ($previous === 'true')
        {
            file_put_contents($file, 'false');
        }
        else
        {
            file_put_contents($file, 'true');
        }
        exit();
    }
?>
```

This is the server side code that updates the file.

index.php

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    function myClick()
    {
        var url = 'script.php'; //put the url for the php
        $.post(url, {}); //avoiding using "done", let the timer update instead
    }

    $("document").ready(
        function()
        {
            setInterval(
                function()
                {
                    $("#theDiv").load("file.txt");
                },
                500
            );
        }
    );
</script>
<div id="theDiv"></div>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="myClick()">
```

And here we are making an ajax request to execute that code from the event handler of the button.

*Note*: the code `$.post(url, {})` will make the request. In this case we are not using the  `done` continuation (that would be executed when the server sends its response) to avoid a race condition with the timer.

---

So far you have been reading `file.txt`. You could take advantage of `script.php` to provide the current value. That will be done in a GET request instead of a POST.

script.php:

```
<?php
    // disable cache by HTTP
    header("Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    // disable cache by IE cache extensions
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
    // disable cache by Proxies
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    $file = 'file.txt';

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
    {
        // POST request

        $previous = file_get_contents($file);
        if ($previous === 'true')
        {
            file_put_contents($file, 'false');
        }
        else
        {
            file_put_contents($file, 'true');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // not POST request, we assume it's GET

        echo file_get_contents($file);
    }
    exit();
?>
```

index.php:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    function myClick()
    {
        var url = 'script.php'; //put the url for the php
        $.post(url, {});
    }

    $("document").ready(
        function()
        {
            setInterval(
                function()
                {
                    $("#theDiv").load('script.php');
                },
                500
            );
        }
    );
</script>
<div id="theDiv"></div>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="myClick()">
```

As you can see, we are now using `script.php` both to read and to write. This facilitates doing checks on the server. For example: maybe not all users are allowed to update the value or to retrieve it.

*Note*: There is a race condition on the saver. If two clients makes requests on the server "at the same time" their updates on the file will overlap and the result will look like only one update happened (instead of two).

---

**Observations**:

1. You may want to do additional checks on the server, for example verify the user session. Maybe not everybody is able to update the state.
2. If you want to do more operation on the same PHP code, you may want to send variables on the POST request. In this case we are not doing that (we just send `{}`).

Also consider:

1. Using [Web Sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Sockets) that provide a more versatile mechanism to push notification to the clients. There are some libraries for this, see the question [Is native PHP support for Web Sockets available?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12204603/402022) where some alternatives are pressented.
2. Using an storage format (such as ini, json, xml...) that will provide your the ability to store more info in the same file.
3. Using a database for storage. Databases will solve the race condition on the server, and provide means to store more complex data. The database engine doesn't need to be MySQL... in fact, for this use a document based database may be better idea (most of them often refered as NoSQL, although some of them actually support SQL).

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! Although there still appears to be an error... :(  I will attach the code so far in my original post.

Comment: @Fjpackard apparently you didn't set the url. See in the code it says `var url = '';` since you decided to use a different file for the php, you need to set it there: `var url = 'script.php';`. [That's observation #3] Edit: I had a mistake too: I wasn't using the variable `url` anyway :P - fixed.

Comment: OK, so it's ALMOST working!! When I click the button on my computer, it changes the status on my IPAD, but it glitches a bit on the computer. Basically on the computer whenever it tries to toggle to FALSE, it becomes FALSE then quickly TRUE again, even though on my iPad it stays as false... Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: OK, that's just weird... Seems to be working now!

Anyway, thanks A HEAP for all the help :):)

Cheers,
Fjpackard.

Comment: @Fjpackard I think I understands what happened... The request of the click is sent and also the timer request is sent, the request from the timer reads the value on the server, then the value on the server is updated by the ongoing request of from the click, this request returns and updates the value on the client, and the request of the timer updates the value on the client with the wrong value that was readed (but not shown) before the click. It may even stay in the wrong value for a while due to server cache.

Comment: @Fjpackard you can mitigate that by adding `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");` also you can skip on the `done` continuation and have the timer do the update removing the race condition. That is, have just `$.post(url, {});` instead of `value = $.post(url, {}).done(
            function(data)
            {
                $('#theDiv').html(data);
            }
        );`.

Comment: Thanks very much for that! (sorry I took so long to reply – I had been on the computer for ages and had to have a break...). It's not a noticeable difference at the moment, but I'm sure it will make it more reliable.

Also, I have been wondering if it is possible to call a JavaScript function using PHP, but triggered by jQuery. (eg. a button press). Hope that makes sense :P  If not I will try to explain a bit better.

Do you think that deserves a new question?

Thanks,
Fjpackard.

Comment: No need to excuse for the delay. I went to sleep myself :), we have different time zones, so it is not rare. On your question, I don't uderstand why you want PHP in the mix, since you say that the action starts in javascript and ends in javascript. You could run code when ajax returns (as we were doing in `done`), or try using PHP output as an external JavaScript script (the content type is needed in the headers). And sure, post it as another. Not just for order, that allows others to help you. Btw, in the previous question @ArunPJohny did help you, may I suggest to accept his answer?

Answer (score 1):

Onclick of that button make one Ajax request using jQuery or simple javascript. Which will update that text file.

How to make Ajax request in jQuery:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Iinjoy